# How to open a navigation bar dropdown using hotkeys like Alt + t using Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Can any one suggest me how to open a bootstrap dropdown menu using keyboard (Hotkeys).If user presses the 'Alt + T' key from keybord the dropdown should get open.How to implement the feature using Angular2 and Typescript.

Comment: where is your code? what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@HostListner` to listen on key press

E.g

```
@HostListner('keypress', ['$event'])
    OpenDropdown(event){
    // get key code from event and if alt+t pressed do your logic

      let code = <KeyboardEvent> event:
 }
```